# One-way starting Thread, can stop but can't enable one more time

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I've got a problem, because I can start a thread, works fine, i can disable it too. But i can't enable it one more time.

I want to create button (switching enable/disable) starting and stopping thread. 
I've got this code:

```
class BunnyhopManager
{
    private static Thread bhopThread;
    public static int LocalUser = 0x00A6E444;  //
    public static int Flags = 0x100;           //  Offsets from game, i'm creating simple hack
    public static int Jump = 0x04AF150C;       //

    public void StartBunnyhop()
    {
        bhopThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Bunnyhop));
        bhopThread.Start();
    }

    private void Bunnyhop()
    {
        // Works fine
        VirtualMemory vm = new VirtualMemory(Main.ProcessName);
        var options = JSONDatabase.GetData(); // Returns dynamic dictionary (<string>, <dynamic>) with JSON values from configuration
        int eJump = Main.Client + Jump;
        LocalUser = Main.Client + LocalUser;
        int LocalPlayer = vm.ReadInt32((IntPtr)LocalUser);
        int xFlags = LocalPlayer + Flags;
        while (Main.bhopStatus) 
        {
            int bhopKey = int.Parse(options["bunnyhop"]["JumpingKeyCode"]);
            while (Main.GetAsyncKeyState(bhopKey) < 0)
            {
                int Flags = vm.ReadInt32((IntPtr)xFlags);
                if (Flags == 257)
                {
                    vm.WriteInt32((IntPtr)eJump, 5); 
                    Thread.Sleep(int.Parse(options["bunnyhop"]["JumpingPoolSleep"]));
                    vm.WriteInt32((IntPtr)eJump, 4); 
                }
            }
        }
        // end of thread
    }
}
```

And my main class, with button:

```
private static BunnyhopManager bhopManager;
public static bool bhopStatus;
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     bhopManager = new BunnyhopManager();
}
private void metroPlayBunnyhop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bhopStatus)
    {
        metroPlayBunnyhop.Text = "Disabled";
        metroPlayBunnyhop.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        bhopStatus = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!Modules.ResearchModule())
        {
            metroPlayBunnyhop.Text = "Open game!";
            return;
        }

        metroPlayBunnyhop.Text = "Enabled";
        metroPlayBunnyhop.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        bhopStatus = true;

        bhopManager.StartBunnyhop();
    }
}
```

Like I said, i can

> enable,
>   disable,
>   but not enable, no crash, no errors, simply thread is not starting.

Comment: First place to look is the ..else.. part in your metroPlayBunnyhop_Click, does (!Modules.ResearchModule()) always return true ? If so you would never reach the StartBunnyhop()

Comment: @secretsquirrel No, it returns true only if game process is started. ResearchModule() is searching for started process. It works, and doesnt stop there.

Comment: Does the thread start and terminate with an unnoticed exception or doesn't it start at all? Can you try and move the initialization stuff out of the thread and into `StartBunnyHop()`? (VirtualMemory vm = new VirtualMemory(Main.ProcessName);
        var options = JSONDatabase.GetData(); // Returns dynamic dictionary (<string>, <dynamic>) with JSON values from configuration
        int eJump = Main.Client + Jump;
        LocalUser = Main.Client + LocalUser;
        int LocalPlayer = vm.ReadInt32((IntPtr)LocalUser);
        int xFlags = LocalPlayer + Flags;)

Comment: @xVacuum the instead of bhopThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Bunnyhop)); just use bhopThread = newThread(Bunnyhop); bhopThread.Start(); - after instantiating the Bunnyhop method. Because new ThreadStart is trying to start a task instance of the task that has already run and finished.

Comment: @secretsquirrel i tried, but when im giving without ThreadStart, thread doesn't start.

Comment: @Haukinger tried too, it just don't start.

Comment: @xVacuums try with task instead of thread

Comment: How do you detect that it does not start? The handler looks good, `StartBunnyHop` looks good, there's no reason `BunnyHop` shouldn't start.

Comment: @Haukinger Hack just doesn't work. :/

Comment: @secretsquirrel I don't want task (or we're talking about other tasks) because it lag program, like freeze. So it doesn't work good.